# Telerik RadEditor not displaying properly

Tags: radeditor, telerik-editor

Whenever I place RadEditor on the page it's not displayed properly but rather displayed in the form of bullets on the page. What might cause this?

Comment: We need more details: what editor exactly? (AJAX? What version?) What other stuff you have in your page?

Answer (score 0):

The provided information is indeed insufficient but try to register the RadEditor's skin css files manually 
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/editor/register-external-skin-vista-radeditor.aspx
or via a CDN Skin server http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/stylesheetmanager-cdn-support.html